# Append to Some(Set[ActorRef])

Tags: scala, akka

I have to use a method that reads a hash map and returns a value associated with a certain key.  This method returns Some(Set[ActorRef]) and I would like to add an element (Actor) to this set (for that key).

I experimented on REPL using a Set[Int] as follows:

```
y2 = y.getOrElse("None")
```

This gets me:

```
y2: Any = Set(8)
```

However, I cannot figure out how to append to this set.

I tried the following but it didn't work

```
y2 ++ 12 
<console>:11: error: value ++ is not a member of Any
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your're having issues because getOrElse("None") is trying to resolve type String (the "None" you passed in) with type Set, resulting in type Any.  You can't use Set operations on Any

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it:

```
var z = y.get

scala> z += 12

scala> z
res3: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(8, 12)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know for certain it's `Some`, then why does it return an `Option` instead of just `Set[ActorRef]`? If not, then you need to decide what to do in case of `None`. E.g. if you want to return a single-element `Set` in this case,

```
val y: Option[Set[ActorRef]] = // some code
y.getOrElse(Set.empty) + anActorRef
```